# MAP a Enum in EntityFramework 6

Tags: entity-framework, enums

I'm trying to create a ENUM in my app it's look like this:

```
public enum Classificacao 
{
    [Description("Terror")]
    Terror = 1,
    [Description("Comédia")]
    Comedia = 1,
    [Description("Terror")]
    Fantasia = 1,  
}
```

I tried to map using Fluent in Entity but does not support to enum.

So how can I map this?

[image: Entity Erro]

Comment: enums can definitely be used as properties of a class, but they cannot be mapped to a table by themselves.  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: @Claies imho, this is the answer.